# Is there a way to change the text colors?

Tags: support

I find the text color on cs.SE hard to read on white background, is there a way to change either the foreground or background color to something else, without resorting to user css scripts? I don't see such options anywhere but maybe they still exist?

Comment: Why do user styles not solve your problem?

Comment: @Raphael Because I am asking for an "official" way?? Sure user styles could solve the problem, but there shouldn't be a problem in the first place. Also I switch between computers so something tied to my account, instead of to the browser, would be preferrable.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. 1) There are ways to request changes to the official themes. In the past, responses have been non-existing. 2) SO has been _extremely_ conservative with adding user preferences. While they have loosened their stance somewhat, the trend is towards _less_ customization (with good reasons). 3) SO has millions of users. Introducing options for every need is clearly impossible. (4) FWIW, with my eyes, screen and config, I have zero trouble reading [cs.SE]. So while your problem is real, it is not universal.

Comment: In summary, I honestly think that user styles are a fair and acceptable solution. It's certainly one that solves your problem _now_ instead of waiting for years (which is, unfortunately, the timespan you have to expect for network-wide SE changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is the only site on SE that has an alternate color scheme ("dark mode") as a built-in option. There is [a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites) to implement this for the entire network, but it is unknown whether or when this might be implemented.

So, for now, there is no other option than resorting to userscripts. [This one](https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode), for example, should work on all SE sites.